# Display profile fields in an extra tab in BuddyPress (Wordpress) using bp-custom.php

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I created an extra tab on the user’s profile page and I would like to display the profile fields in it.

This is how I created the extra tab in the first place, I created a new bp-custom.php with this inside

```
function profile_new_nav_item() {

    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_nav_item(
        array(
            'name'                => 'About',
            'slug'                => 'about',
          'default_subnav_slug' => 'extra_sub_tab', // We add this submenu item below
            'screen_function'     => 'view_manage_tab_main'
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_nav_item', 10 );

function view_manage_tab_main() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'bp_template_content_main_function' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
}

function bp_template_content_main_function() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) );
    }
}

function profile_new_subnav_item() {
    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
        'name'            => 'Extra Sub Tab',
        'slug'            => 'extra_sub_tab',
        'parent_url'      => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->bp_nav[ 'about' ][ 'slug' ] . '/',
        'parent_slug'     => $bp->bp_nav[ 'about' ][ 'slug' ],
        'position'        => 10,
        'screen_function' => 'view_manage_sub_tab_main'
    ) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_subnav_item', 10 );

function view_manage_sub_tab_main() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'bp_template_content_sub_function' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
}

function bp_template_content_sub_function() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'you are here';
    } else {
        wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) );
    }
}
```

See where it says `echo 'you are here';` in the last function, I would like to display the profile fields there. I have the code below but I can’t figure out how to embed it there.

If I `echo bp_the_profile_field()` I get the following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function the_profile_field() on null

The code below works perfectly on another page, it fetches all the available fields.

```
<div class="bp-widget <?php bp_the_profile_group_slug(); ?>">
<h4><?php bp_the_profile_group_name(); ?></h4>
<table class="profile-fields">
    <?php while ( bp_profile_fields() ) : bp_the_profile_field(); ?>
        <?php if ( bp_field_has_data() ) : ?>
            <tr<?php bp_field_css_class(); ?>>
                <td class="label"><?php bp_the_profile_field_name(); ?></td>
                <td class="data"><?php bp_the_profile_field_value(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        do_action( 'bp_profile_field_item' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
echo 'you are here';
```

With this:

```
bp_get_template_part( 'members/single/profile/profile-loop' );
```